# Chart JS background color line overlapped by annotation

Tags: javascript, html, angular, chart.js

I have box annotation and line with fill color. Border of line on top of annotation, but background color on bottom. Could anyone solve this problem ? Thanks a lot!

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/yunusffz/pen/mdegKrd)

```
Create 2 line with 1 line fill +1
```

Condition with annotation 
[image]

Condition without annotation 
[image]

Expectation 
[image]

Comment: Can you share the code you're currently using for it? What version of chart.js are you using?

Comment: I use chart js 2.9.3, example code in the post

Comment: can anyone help me please...